# What possible XSS vectors can we use?

Tags: web, xss

I am working on creating some sort of POC of XSS. And I am getting a problem in this with meta tags.

While checking the source code, this is how the user input entered:

```html
<meta content='https://site/?lol=1' property='og:url'>
```

The lol=1 can be controlled by the user input. I have tried many ways to get XSS prompt here. But no luck so far.

Can anyone please help me out with this one?

Answer (score -1):

You should write what you have tried and why it did not work. My initial thought would be

```
'><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>
```